# Create a temp table and joining that with another table in the same snowflake query

Tags: join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two snowflake tables, A and B

TABLE A

[image]

TABLE B

[image]

I want to create temp table based off of table A and join with TABLE B in the same query
something like below but it gives me `SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 21 unexpected 'create'.` error

```
 SELECT A.*,B.* FROM (create or replace temporary table TMP_TBL1 as 
                          SELECT * FROM A) A
                          JOIN B B ON A.ADDRESS = B.ADDRESS
```

Answer (score 0):

Create table has to be a separate statement:

```
create or replace temporary table TMP_TBL1 
as 
SELECT * FROM A;

SELECT A.*,B.* 
FROM TMP_TBL1 AS  A
JOIN B AS B 
  ON A.ADDRESS = B.ADDRESS;
```

Alternative approach is CTE (Common Table Expression), but without materialization:

```
WITH TMP_TBL1 AS ( 
    SELECT * FROM A
)
SELECT A.*,B.* 
FROM TMP_TBL1 AS  A
JOIN B AS B 
  ON A.ADDRESS = B.ADDRESS;
```

Comment: CTE would be a better approach!